# Check for applicable Group query for shopping cart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have problem for one of discount check condition. I have tables structure as below:

**Cart** table `(id, customerid, productid)`
    **Group** table `(groupid, groupname, discountamount)`
    **Group Products** table `(groupproductid, groupid, productid)`

While placing an order, there will be multiple items in cart, I want to check those items with top most group if that group consists of all product shopping cart have?

**Example**: 
If group 1 consists 2 products and those two products exists in cart table then group 1 discount should be returned.

please help

Comment: How is top most group determined? Lowest `groupid`? highest `discountamount`?

Comment: group which is added earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky, without having real table definitions nor sample data. So I've made some up:

```
create table Carts(
    id int,
    customerid int,
    productid int
)
create table Groups(
    groupid int,
    groupname int,
    discountamount int
)
create table GroupProducts(
    groupproductid int,
    groupid int,
    productid int
)

insert into Carts (id,customerid,productid) values
(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(3,1,4),
(4,2,2),
(5,2,3)
insert into Groups (groupid,groupname,discountamount) values
(1,1,10),
(2,2,15),
(3,3,20)
insert into GroupProducts (groupproductid,groupid,productid) values
(1,1,1),
(2,1,5),
(3,2,2),
(4,2,4),
(5,3,2),
(6,3,3)

;With MatchedProducts as (
    select
        c.customerid,gp.groupid,COUNT(*) as Cnt
    from
        Carts c
            inner join
        GroupProducts gp
            on
                c.productid = gp.productid
    group by
        c.customerid,gp.groupid
), GroupSizes as (
    select groupid,COUNT(*) as Cnt from GroupProducts group by groupid
), MatchingGroups as (
    select
        mp.*
    from
        MatchedProducts mp
            inner join
        GroupSizes gs
            on
                mp.groupid = gs.groupid and
                mp.Cnt = gs.Cnt
)
select * from MatchingGroups
```

Which produces this result:

```
customerid  groupid     Cnt
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           2
2           3           2
```

What we're doing here is called "relational division" - if you want to search elsewhere for that term. In my current results, each customer only matches one group - if there are multiple matches, we need some tie-breaking conditions to determine which group to report. I prompted with two suggestions in comments (lowest `groupid` or highest `discountamount`). Your response of "added earlier" doesn't help - we don't have a column which contains the addition dates of groups. Rows have no inherent ordering in SQL.

We would do the tie-breaking in the definition of `MatchingGroups` and the final select:

```
MatchingGroups as (
    select
        mp.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mp.customerid ORDER BY /*Tie break criteria here */) as rn
    from
        MatchedProducts mp
            inner join
        GroupSizes gs
            on
                mp.groupid = gs.groupid and
                mp.Cnt = gs.Cnt
)
select * from MatchingGroups where rn = 1
```